# Replace literal space with regex space

Tags: bash, regular-expression, string, replace

I want to change a string from

```
This is a string
```

to

```
This\sis\sa\sstring
```

but tr is not working for me no matter if I escape the `\` or not

```
string="This is a string"
regex=$(echo "$string" | tr " " "\\s")
printf "$regex"
```

I just get

```
Thississasstring
```

Comment: With `printf` you always want to use the format specifier: `printf "%s" "$regex"` -- this ensures that any % characters in the string are not misinterpreted by printf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue with your approach, I think, is that `tr` transliterates *single* characters - so even if you successfully quote `'\\s'` it's not going to work the way you want (it would likely just replace space with `\`).

In this case, you don't need external utilities at all:

```
string="This is a string"
echo "${string// /\\s}"
This\sis\sa\sstring
```